# Good design for parallel connection with multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I try to calculate a little heavy work using multiprocessing in python.
I am a beginner of multiprocessing although I just know about some important classes like Lock, Process, etc.

The problem can be simplified to the simple time-evolution:

```
for t in ts:
    #common_datas would be numpy.ndarray        
    common_datas =  time_evolution(common_datas)

    #I want to parallel the following for-loop. (probably len=~100)
    for each_data in common_datas:
        each_data = do_some_heavy_works(each_data)
    #end

    #continue if all paralleled loop finish.
```

I don't think it is a good way to create many processes for each t loop.
So I would create all the processes before t's for-loop and make the main process connect with each process after the time evolution.

My question is

1. How to keep the child processes alive until the parent process send *each_data* to it?
2. How to wait until all paralleled loop finish?

I would like to know a algorithm which contains the classes in multiprocessing.

Comment: `from multiprocessing import Pool` pool of 5 processes, `p = Pool(5)`

Comment: In the case of Pool, I worry about the overhead because it's created every time computing t's for-loop.